App Script Project deleted - how to restore it?
I deleted a project by mistake and can't retrieve it. Is there any way to restore it?
I tried restoring an earlier version of the gsheet file to which the app script project was linked. I have tried restoring to yesterday all the files in the drive account, but I can never find the app script project that was deleted. Is there any way to restore the deleted project? In executions I still see the project, but if I click on it it gives me error

Have you checked the trash?
If it's not in the trash, I don't think it's possible to retrieve it based on the Google documentation I've read:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/projects#delete-file
